# Git tag doesn't return the last tag

Tags: git

I'm trying to understand why the command "git describe --tags --abbrev=0" doesn't return me the last tag I've created with Git.

That's what I've done.

Step 1: Tag creation

I've executed the following commands:

```
 git tag 1.0.1
 git tag 1.0.2
 git tag 1.0.3
 git tag 1.0.4
 git tag 1.0.5
 git tag 1.0.6
 git tag 1.0.7
 git tag 1.0.8
 git tag 1.0.9
 git tag 1.0.10
 git tag 1.0.11
 git tag 1.0.12
```

Step 2 - Getting the list of all tags:

I've executed the following command:

```
 git tag
```

The result is the following:

```
 1.0.0
 1.0.1
 1.0.10
 1.0.11
 1.0.12
 1.0.2
 1.0.3
 1.0.4
 1.0.5
 1.0.6
 1.0.7
 1.0.8
 1.0.9
```

Step 3 - Getting the last tag:

I've executed the following command:

```
 git describe --tags --abbrev=0
```

The result is the following:

```
 1.0.1
```

Shouldn't it be "1.0.12"?

Comment: Note that "last tag" could mean different things, some of which might be: 1.) sorted alphabetically, 2.) sorted numerically (probably included in #1 automatically), 3.) sorted by creation date if it's annotated, 4.) the latest commit the tag is pointing to (which could be further broken down by author date or committer date), 5.) tag which points to the closest commit to the tip of the currently checked out commit, graph-points-wise.

Answer (score 4):

Note that this `git describe --tags --abbrev=0` is an exception:

[Git - git-describe Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe/2.33.0#_description)

> By default (without --all or --tags) `git describe` only shows annotated tags. For more information about creating annotated tags see the -a and -s options to [git-tag[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag).

And you have used none annotated tags:

[Git - git-tag Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#_description)

> Tag objects (created with `-a`, `-s`, or `-u`) are called "annotated" tags; they **contain a creation date**, the tagger name and e-mail, a tagging message, and an optional GnuPG signature. Whereas a "lightweight" tag is simply a name for an object (usually a commit object).
>
> Annotated tags are meant for release while lightweight tags are meant for private or temporary object labels. For this reason, some git commands for naming objects (like `git describe`) will ignore lightweight tags by default.

So since you didn't used annotated tags, so there is no creation date for them. This means git doesn't have information which tag is older and selects one randomly (first which he can find) if they are pointing to same commit.

So try use annotated tags, then git will have means to order tags based on they creation date.

Answer (score 2):

`git describe` is not the same as `git tag`. `git describe` is used to describe a commit. `git tag` is used to list all tags.
`git describe --tags --abbrev=0` will describe the commit with the closest tag.
If you want to get the last tag, you can use

```bash
git tag | tail -n 1
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "closest tag" means, and how that differs from "last tag"?

Comment: The closest tag is determined by the number of commits between the tag and the commit you are describing. It deffers from the last tag in that it is the closest tag to the commit you are describing.

Comment: run example from question and you will get `1.0.9` not `1.0.12`!

Comment: Assuming `HEAD` is up-to-date, and assuming a linear history, shouldn't those always be the same?